# Mysql auto sharding

Tags: mysql, sharding

I am trying to understand the automatic way of Sharding. I understand there is a way to do sharding through application logic (for example, id > 100 go to DB B, < 100 go to DB A)

However, is there a way that the sharding and partitioning is done automatically by the mysql engine? In this case, application will not care about which db to write to, and the mysql engine will do the allocation based on the query executed?

Comment: *is there a way that the sharding and partitioning is done automatically by the mysql engine?* No such service in MySQL.

Comment: Check out "Spider".